# How to run groovy script in Blazemeter, which try to get access to csv file data?

Tags: csv, groovy, jmeter, blazemeter

I have some Jmeter script on groovy

```
1.upto(${amount_of_items}, { index ->
def data = new File('data/ids.csv').readLines().get(index).split(',') 
def attr = [:]
attr.put('id', data[0].toInteger()) 
def attributes = [:]
def param = [:]
param.put('quantity', ${quantity})
param.put('status_id', 4)
attributes.put('statuses', [param])
attributes.put('identity', attr)
adjustItems.add(attributes)
})
```

Is there any solution to get access to my csv which I try to parse from Blazemeter?

```
def data = new File('data/ids.csv').readLines().get(index).split(',')
```

Could I upload my csv to Shared Folder in Blazemeter and use it in script?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a problem to access your file in BlazeMeter given you upload it to the shared folder. See [Shared Folders](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002087717-Shared-Folders-Shared-Folders) article for more details.

Also according to [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:

> Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.

> When using this feature, ensure your script code **does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement.** Instead use script parameters.

So I would recommend amending your code to use `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance like:

```
1.upto(vars.get('amount_of_items') as int, { index ->
    def data = new File('data/ids.csv').readLines().get(index).split(',')
    def attr = [:]
    attr.put('id', data[0].toInteger())
    def attributes = [:]
    def param = [:]
    param.put('quantity', vars.get('quantity') as int)
    param.put('status_id', 4)
    attributes.put('statuses', [param])
    attributes.put('identity', attr)
    adjustItems.add(attributes)
})
```

Comment: But there is no info about setting absolute path to this file from shared folder, relative path, for example, "folder/filename" is not working, when I try to access to it from groovy script